# Unclosable progressbar in WPF

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

I am looking for a forced `ProgressBar` that cannot be closed or canceled. I tried to make this window, but it can always be closed by ALT-F4.

I want to close the window when the process is finished.

```
<Window x:Class="BWCRenameUtility.View.BusyProgressBar"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="BusyProgressBar" WindowStyle="None" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Exporting..."/>
        <ProgressBar Width="300" Height="20" IsIndeterminate="True" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want a unclosable `ProgressBar` but un unclosable `Window` (a progress bar cannot be closed)!

To do this, use the event [`Window.Closing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx) which occurs after a close request but before the effective close.

In your XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="BWCRenameUtility.View.BusyProgressBar"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="BusyProgressBar" WindowStyle="None" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Closing="BusyProgressBar_OnClosing">

    <!-- Your code -->

</Window>
```

In the `BusyProgressBar` class, cancel the close request by setting [`CancelEventArgs.Cancel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel.aspx) to `true`:

```
private void BusyProgressBar_OnClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;  // Cancels the close request
}
```

### Update

Instead of using the event `Window.Closing`, an easier solution is to override [`Window.OnClosing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.onclosing.aspx).

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;  // Cancels the close request
    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

This way, you don't have to change anything to your XAML.

Comment: This would never ever close the window anymore, but that is not true, because I want to close it when the process is finished.

Comment: Are you serious ? What about making an if around it ?

Comment: Why so complicated? `e.Cancel = !ProgressFinished;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just handle Closing event of the window and put `e.Cancel = true`